Angular Material Table - how to disable row click on a specific column?
I have an Angular component with the HTML hereunder:
<table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-table class="content-table" matSort matSortDirection="asc">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="column1">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="nbOfEvent">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>Number of event</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.eventCount}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="displayUsageMb">
    <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header="displayUsageMb" *matHeaderCellDef>Usage in MB</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.usageBytes / (1024*1024) | number: '1.2-2'}}</td>
  </ng-container>
        
  <!-- Action Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="whitespace-nowrap actions-column">

      <a mat-raised-button color="primary"
        (click)="activate(row.name, row.eventCount); clicked = true;"
        [disabled]="clicked || row.eventCount > 0">Activate</a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [routerLink]="['/details', row.name]" class="row-hover"></tr>
</table>

I display a table where I can click on the row (record) in any column to see the details of the displayed record (routerLink on the <tr>).
I have now also a column with several buttons (sample above shows one only) and I have a side effect when I disable a button in this row, if I click the disabled button, it takes the event for clicking the row and navigate to the details page.
I read some techiques and tried to add:
$event.stopPropagation();
after my clicked = true; in the (click) event of the button but it is not working (still have the redirect).
As a workaround I put the code [routerLink]="['/details', row.name]" in each <td> except the one containing the action buttons.
Is there any better way to address this problem by keeping one [routerLink] code in the <tr> element?

stopPropagation should work. how did  you apply it?

@Andrei
I just updated the (click) event like this (click)="activate(row.name, row.eventCount); clicked = true;$event.stopPropagation()"

try same thing on td, instead of a element. link only occupies a small portion of the cell

@Andrei you was right, just adding  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" on the td where are the button deactivate the column whatever the state of the button. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it.
